# Pass Data between screens with Lightswitch HTML client

Tags: parameter-passing, default-value, visual-studio-lightswitch

My application starts with a `Browse` screenwhere you choose an employee. You are then brought to another `Browse` screenwhich displays records for that employee. On the second browse screen I have a button which opens an `Add/Edit` screen.

> I would like to default a field on my `Add/Edit` screen to be the `EmployeeID` which was selected on the first `Browse` screen

My application uses views to populate the `Browse` screens with distinct lists, but the `Add/Edit` references the table directly. For this reason I have been unable to create a relationship between my application `DataSources`

> Currently I can default the `CreateDate` value with the code below but the second line is not returning the `EmployeeID` as I want

```
myapp.AddTimesheetRecord.created = function (screen) {
    // Write code here.
    screen.TBG_KeepInTimesheet.CreateDate = new Date;
    screen.TBG_KeepInTimesheet.EmployeeID = myapp.activeDataWorkspace.WPEBrattleData.TBG_V_KeepInTimeSheet_Details.EmployeeID;
};
```

Here is an [Image of my `Add/Edit`](http://s1373.photobucket.com/user/Gruff_from_Stack/media/AddTimesheetRecordScreen_zpsdalsbokb.jpg.html?filters[user]=140580570&filters[recent]=1&sort=1&o=0) screen designer, note that currently `EmployeeID` will be blank when run with the code above

Here is an [Image of my second `Browse`](http://s1373.photobucket.com/user/Gruff_from_Stack/media/ViewEmployeeProjectsScreen_zpsqiat9nt8.jpg.html?filters[user]=140580570&filters[recent]=1&sort=1&o=1) screen designer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option would be to edit the tap action of your AddNewRecord Command Bar Button and use the 'Write my own method' to implement a AddNewRecord_Tap function along the following lines:

```js
myapp.ViewEmployeeProjects.AddNewRecord_Tap_execute = function (screen) {
    myapp.showAddTimesheetRecord(null, {
        beforeShown: function (addScreen) {
            var newItem = new myapp.TBG_KeepInTimesheet();
            newItem.EmployeeID = screen.TBG_V_KeepInTimeSheet_Employee.EmployeeID;
            addScreen.TBG_KeepInTimesheet = newItem;
        }
    });
};
```

This approach allows you to use the selected employee id (from your Browse screen) to initialise your new time-sheet record prior to showing your AddEdit screen.

Comment: Fantastic! This worked perfectly (after updating the `addScreen` statement which is missing a 'T') Thank you very much!

Comment: The cut 'n' paste missing T should be back :-) and I'm glad it did the trick